# HtmlUnit download a pdf

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am trying to download a PDF with HtmlUnit v.2.27.

I tried different approaches, with attachments, adding WebWindowListener ... but I can't download the PDF file.

Any clue how to do this ?

Details of the web and test data are hardcoded in the web.

```
     public void start() throws Exception {

    try {

     String folioNumber = "278E1D22C5747F961";
     String rut = "21759297-6";

        try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.BEST_SUPPORTED)) {

            webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
            webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
            webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
            webClient.getOptions().setActiveXNative(true);
            webClient.getOptions().setAppletEnabled(true);
            webClient.getOptions().setPrintContentOnFailingStatusCode(true);
            webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());

            final HtmlPage home = webClient.getPage("https://www.afpmodelo.cl/AFP/Centro-de-ayuda/Herramientas/Validacion-Certificados.aspx");

            HtmlInput rutInput = home.getFirstByXPath("//*[@id=\"ContentPlaceHolder1_txt_RUT\"]");
            rutInput.setValueAttribute(rut);

            HtmlInput folioInput = home.getFirstByXPath("//*[@id=\"ContentPlaceHolder1_txt_FOLIO\"]");
            folioInput.setValueAttribute(folioNumber);

            HtmlImage captchaImg = home.getFirstByXPath("//*[@id=\"imgCaptcha\"]");

            File imageFile = new File("/tmp/AfpModeloSpider" + LocalDateTime.now().toString() + "captcha.jpg");
            captchaImg.saveAs(imageFile);               

            HtmlInput captchaInput = home.getFirstByXPath("//*[@id=\"ContentPlaceHolder1_txtCaptcha\"]");
            captchaInput.setValueAttribute(captchaResult);

            HtmlInput validarButton = home.getFirstByXPath("//*[@id=\"ContentPlaceHolder1_btn_VALIDAR_CERT\"]");

            HtmlPage result = validarButton.click();
            webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(6000);

            saveFile(result.getWebResponse().getContentAsStream());             


        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "no luck" mean? The file disappears, you get an error message, the code doesn't compile, ...?

Comment: means I can't download the pdf file. No error messages. It's compiling.

Comment: Do you have the ability to get the PDF url? or is it generated with Javascript?

Comment: This code it's working with htmlunit version 2.28-SNAPSHOT. 
So, looks like the issue was in the lib.